# How to control formatting when dumping to JSON?

Tags: python, json

Sorry I'm new to database management so I don't know the correct terminology, I'll show my code and try to explain what I want to do.

This is my current code:

```
products = {}
for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=11, max_row=17, min_col=2, max_col=8, values_only=True):
    boxsetname = value[4]
    BookName = value[1]
    bookdetails = {
        "ISBN1": value[0],
        "ISBN2": value[6],
        "note": value[5]
    }
    products[BookName] = bookdetails

print(json.dumps(products))
```

Which outputs to json in this format:

```
{"Billionaire Boy": {
    "ISBN1": "9780007371082",
    "ISBN2": "david walliams paperback",
    "note": "music magpie"},
"Mr Stink": {
    "ISBN1": "9780007279067",
    "ISBN2": null,
    "note": null},
"The Boy In The Dress": {
    "ISBN1": "9780007279043",
    "ISBN2": null,
    "note": null},
"10th Anniversary": {
    "ISBN1": "9780099525370",
    "ISBN2": "10th Anniversary patterson paperback",
    "note": "MM"},
"7th Heaven": {
    "ISBN1": "9780099514541",
    "ISBN2": "7th patterson paperback ",
    "note": "MM 7th patterson paperback "},
}}
```

However I need to use the string stored in boxsetname to act as a container for the books in the set i.e

```
{"boxset1":
    {"Billionaire Boy": {
        "ISBN1": "9780007371082",
        "ISBN2": "david walliams paperback",
        "note": "music magpie"},
    "Mr Stink": {
        "ISBN1": "9780007279067",
        "ISBN2": null,
        "note": null},
    "The Boy In The Dress": {
        "ISBN1": "9780007279043",
        "ISBN2": null,
        "note": null},}
{"boxset2":
    "10th Anniversary": {
        "ISBN1": "9780099525370",
        "ISBN2": "10th Anniversary patterson paperback",
        "note": "MM"},
    "7th Heaven": {
        "ISBN1": "9780099514541",
        "ISBN2": "7th patterson paperback ",
        "note": "MM 7th patterson paperback "},
}}
```

I don't know how to achieve this and am lost searching google because I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Hint: why does your code **not** simply output in the form `{"ISBN1": "9780007371082", "ISBN2": "david walliams paperback", "note": "music magpie"}`, but instead add the layer with book names? Now, just *apply that technique again*.

Comment: Another hint: try feeding your expected output back to `json.loads`. Notice where it fails? Does the expected value for a `"boxset"` key contain exactly one book's worth of data, or more than one? Okay, so what do you need there?

Comment: `products.setdefault(boxsetname, {})[BookName] = bookdetails`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried 
```products[boxsetname] = BookName
products[BookName] = bookdetails```
Which almost worked but for some reason the first book in each boxset would not be dumped with their details, can't wrap my head around why

Comment: @ekhumoro fantastic thank you works perfectly, I'll read up on the .setdefault method!

Comment: The key here is you need to create another level of nesting similar to the way you already use the `Bookname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `collections.defaultdict` to create a nested dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

# When a "boxsetname" is added, the default value of that key will be a new,
# nested dictionary
products = defaultdict(dict)

for value in [['9780007371082','Billionaire Boy','v2','v3','boxset1','note1','isbn1'],
              ['9780007279067','Mr Stink','v2','v3','boxset1','note2','isbn2'],
              ['9780099525370','10th Anniversary','v2','v3','boxset2','note3','isbn3']]:
    boxsetname = value[4]
    BookName = value[1]
    bookdetails = {
        "ISBN1": value[0],
        "ISBN2": value[6],
        "note": value[5]
    }
    # Being a defaultdict, adding a new boxsetname will add a new dictionary for
    # books, else the book will be added to an existing boxset.
    products[boxsetname][BookName] = bookdetails

print(json.dumps(products,indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "boxset1": {
    "Billionaire Boy": {
      "ISBN1": "9780007371082",
      "ISBN2": "isbn1",
      "note": "note1"
    },
    "Mr Stink": {
      "ISBN1": "9780007279067",
      "ISBN2": "isbn2",
      "note": "note2"
    }
  },
  "boxset2": {
    "10th Anniversary": {
      "ISBN1": "9780099525370",
      "ISBN2": "isbn3",
      "note": "note3"
    }
  }
}
```